# Display two options within select box side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to shown an select box with two options beside eachother within the list. It is proving difficult and I cant seem to find any libraries that offer this functionality. For example:

```
<select>

<option x><option y>
<option x><option y>
<option x><option y>
<option x><option y>
<option x><option y>

</select>
```

You can see an example of this working [here](http://qualityeyes.com/1-day-acuvue-moist) (Sorry i cant do a jsfiddle as obviously i can't get it working!) with the "Right Eye PWR:" dropdown list.

I have tried to move the option based on its content by style i.e. floating left with a width of 50% and floating right but I'm not having much luck with that (Especially as across browsers it wouldn't be a great way of doing it). Any suggestions about the best way to tackle this problem would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible, sorry. As an alternative, you can put 2 separate select options next to each other, and compare the selected values if you need to. By the way, why do you want to do this? There might be another problem at the root of this solution you are looking for, a problem that's easier to solve.

Comment: You'd have to use some Javascript to display it like that. It's not possible with default html.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using a type of jquery library to configure it to act as needed. Just couldn't seem to find one! Guess I'll keep on looking! Cheers for the headsup guys

Comment: Use the Source!  You have a working example linked from your question.  Look at the CSS and see what, if any, "hooks" there may be to jQuery or something like it.

Comment: Buzz, it seems to use "gentle select" jquery library! Don't know why I didn't just think of looking at that... Cheers mate

Comment: @RichardCripps do share your answer when you have it! its ok to answer your own question and mark it as the answer

Comment: Thank you for the advice @g_m , I've put in an answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do this you need to be able to download [this](https://github.com/shawnchin/jquery-gentleSelect) jquery library. It enables you to sort a select drop down menu by columns. By adding in this to your site:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#selector').gentleSelect(); // apply gentleSelect with default options
                    });

    </script>
```

After this has been added, through using their readme you can select a certain amount of columns to display in your select box.

You can change the functionality (Like in my question putting them side by side with positive and negative) by adding a bit of custom code.

[You can see a Js Bin here](http://jsbin.com/yisiporahe/1/edit?html,js,output)