# Select box options listing side by side not one above other

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

> THIS is a duplicate of the [Display two options within select box side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444227/display-two-options-within-select-box-side-by-side)

I'm utilising JQuery Selectric plugin for select elements using untouched default css provided for the plugin. All looks fine except that the dropdown list never shows one option under another as you always expect but rather they show side by side on one row. Even as I reduce the width of the element, they never show normally.

In other words, they show as follows.

SELECT BOX

Option1   Option2   Option3   Option4 etc

The select is within a div that is float:left but no matter what style I try to add to the element, the options never show properly. They are, however, properly separate choices with correct mouseover effects etc - just side by side not one under other.

Any ideas how I can get the element to show in the standard vertical listing format?

Thanks.

HTML is as simple as I've suggested.

```
<select>
<option value="1">Apples</option>
<option value="2">Bananas</option>
<option value="3">Peaches</option>
<option value="4">Pears</option>
</select>
```

The containing divs are as follows

```
<div id="page">
<div id="main">
<div id="info">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Styles as follows

```
div#page {position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;top:110px;width:100%;}
div#main {margin:auto;left:0px;right:0px;text-align:left;max-width:1100px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;}
div#info {float:left;width:46%;margin-left:4%}
```

Comment: Share your html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display two options within select box side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444227/display-two-options-within-select-box-side-by-side)

Comment: @chirag - not really a duplicate as this is unintended behaviour and not solved by another plugin as it is not supposed to be happening in first place

Comment: ok so I eliminated everything from the file except the Selectric plugin and it made no difference so I guess there's a fundamental issue that no-one else has seen - will have to take it up on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a process of elimination it seems that the CSS Flex styling for 'ul' elements caused this behaviour. So I guess if you actually want this to happen then use display:flex etc to mess with the dropdown options.